Adding number of days to date in Mapforce
I have an XML that has a date format of 20230101 and I need to add 60 days to this date when mapping it over. this is a random date so it always changes and we are using XSLT2. I can not figure out how to do this in XSLT, does anyone know a way to do this in Mapforce.

Use e.g. xs:date(replace('20230101', '([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})', '$1-$2-$3')) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P60D').

I understand that but I dont understand how to get that into Mapforce

@user3818712, I posted an XPath 2.0 expression you can therefore use with any XSLT 2 stylesheet; I don't use map force so I can't tell you how to integrate a particular XPath expression in that environment. In XSLT you would use e.g. <xsl:template match="name-of-input-element-with-date"><output-date><xsl:value-of select="xs:date(replace(., '([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})', '$1-$2-$3')) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P60D')"/></output-date></xsl:template>.

You can use the build in function datetime-add of altovas basic libary
Add your date (convert to Date-Time before) as first parameter
Add P60D as second parameter
If needed remove time (convert back to just date)

